# gradle dsl method not found: ' armv7a'

Tags: android, odroid

my build.grandle code is this one:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.assus.appweather"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk {
            moduleName = "odroid_weather"
            abiFilter "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs 'main/src/libs'
        }
    }
    productFlavors{
        x86 {
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86"
            }
            armv7a{
                ndk {
                    abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
                }
            }
        }
    }


}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'

}
```

and when I build my project, always this error is shown : 
gradle dsl method not found: ' armv7a'
Gradle sync failed: Gradle DSL method not found: 'armv7a()'
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
some one can help me please !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant to have a productFlavors that looks like this instead (it looks like you missing a closing brace):

```
productFlavors{
    x86 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "x86"
        }
    }
    armv7a {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help.  Please don't forget to accept this answer as the correct one.